# Wii MotionPlus support

Tags: c++, c, wii, wiimote, wiiuse

I am developing a PC application that interacts with the [Wiimote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote). So far I have been using the [wiiuse library](http://www.wiiuse.net/), which has worked great.

However, wiiuse does not support the [MotionPlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_MotionPlus) extension.
I have heard of extensions to implement this by [Dolphin](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu/) and [libogc](http://libogc.devkitpro.org/) but have not managed to locate this code.

Do you know of code that implements support for MotionPlus with wiiuse, or another C based libary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that [fWIIne](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fwiine/files/) has a modded version with MotionPlus support, though only in the [release zip file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fwiine/files/fwiine/0.4/fWIIne_v0.4_bin_src_winxp_matlab.zip/download) and not the repository.