# Are there any good Wiimote APIs (C/C++) out there that include Wii Motion Plus?

Tags: c++, c, api, wiimote, wii

Hello I was looking around on the internet and I was unable to find anything concrete. I would like to find a good Wiimote API (in C or C++) that also implements usage of the Wii Motion Plus accessory. If anyone knows of any good ones it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846844/wii-motionplus-support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [WiiYourself](http://wiiyourself.gl.tter.org/).
You might need to adapt one thing or another, such as the connection timeout, but it works quite well.

Take also a look at WiiBrew's [Wiimote page](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote) 
and [Wiimote driver page](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote_Driver).